# iOS7 How to change the coordinates UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview

iOS6 I use willPresentAlertView: change the UIAlertView coordinates,but iOS7 no effect.
I have three UITableViews of iPad,I want to display UIAlertView in the right list.How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own UIAlertView substitute by taking advantage of the new iOS 7 "custom modal transition animation" feature. This lets you make a small modal view that appears over the rest of your interface, anywhere you want, and with any content you want. Much better than UIAlertView and it's all totally legal and above-board.

Comment: Here's a tutorial article I wrote about how to do that. http://programming.oreilly.com/2014/01/transcending-uialertview-on-ios-7.html